# Memory error joining pdf files

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, out-of-memory

I'm building a program in C# that reads 3 PDF files, performs some sorting based on the user ID and generates an output PDF file.
It currently generates 1254 pdf files(approx 5 MB each) and when I try to join them, throws an Out Of Memmory Exception .

How can I join these files, considering that it results in a 4 GB file size?
The following code joins all PDF files into a single output file.

```
public void CombineMultiplePDFs(string[] fileNames, string outFile)
    {
        int pageOffset = 0;
        ArrayList master = new ArrayList();
        int f = 0;
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        while (f < fileNames.Length)
        {
            // we create a reader for a certain document
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileNames[f]);
            reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
            // we avisorieve the total number of pages
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            pageOffset += n;
            if (f == 0)
            {
                // step 1: creation of a document-object
                document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
                writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create));
                // step 3: we open the document
                document.Open();
            }
            // step 4: we add content
            for (int i = 0; i < n; )
            {
                ++i;
                if (writer != null)
                {


                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    writer.AddPage(page);


                }
            }
            PRAcroForm form = reader.AcroForm;
            if (form != null && writer != null)
            {
                writer.CopyAcroForm(reader);
            }
            f++;
        }
        // step 5: we close the document
        if (document != null)
        {
            document.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand the situation very well. First you have 3 files, then 1254 files... Why would anyone ever want to join more than a thousand 5MB PDF files? Are you expecting people to open such monstrous files that would come out of this?

Comment: each files of 1254 is a one page of these docs. All of this will be printed.

Comment: Are there chances that certain resources repeat in the 1000+ source files? In that case,  have you tried `PdfSmartCopy`, maybe on smaller packages of some dozens of source files?

Comment: Hi man, this is that you tell for me worked, thanks. Please post your answer for me choose as the best answer.